# changing text file format using awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file like the following example:

```
chr10:100007446-100008677   153 154
chr8:100007446-100008677    165 166
chr6:100007446-100008677    170 171
chr1:100007446-100008677    2   3
```

I want to change some elements in my file.

1. in the input file the columns are tab separated
2. in the 1st column I want to keep only `"chr"` and the number after that, like the output below
3. the `2nd` column is `"the 1st number just after ':' in the 1st column"` plus the number in the 2nd column in the corresponding row.
4. the `3rd` column is `"the new number in the 2nd column + 1"`
   here is a small example of expected output:

   ```
   chr10   100007599   100007600
   chr8    100007611   100007612
   chr6    100007616   100007617
   chr1    100007448   100007449
   ```

I wrote the following piece of code in `awk`:

```
awk -F "\t"":""-" ' {print $1 = $1,  print $2 = $2+4, print $2 = $2+$4+1}' file.txt > out.txt
```

but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
awk -F ":|-|[[:blank:]]*" '{print $1,$2+$4,$2+$4+1}' file
```

This outputs:

```
chr10 100007599 100007600
chr8 100007611 100007612
chr6 100007616 100007617
chr1 100007448 100007449
```

If you want your output to be tab-delimited, you can use (per suggestion of William Pursell)

```
awk -F ":|-|[[:blank:]]*" '{print $1,$2+$4,$2+$4+1}' OFS="\t" file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":|-|[[:blank:]]*";OFS="\t"}
     {print $1,$2+$4,$2+$4+1}' file
```

which leads to:

```
chr10   100007599       100007600
chr8    100007611       100007612
chr6    100007616       100007617
chr1    100007448       100007449
```

*note: SO does not allow tabs in verbatim*

Furthermore, if you are certain that the input only contains tabs and no spaces, you can use `-F ":|-|\t"` to define the field separator.

**Remark:** Be aware that tabs are evil. They can be considered to be good field separators, but when you visualise it in an editor or on the screen, everything depends on how your system interprets how wide a tab is. Is it 4, 8 or 17?

Comment: Just needs OFS='\t'

Comment: (I guess I'm interpreting "in the input file the columns are tab separated" to mean that the desired output contains tabs....)

Comment: @WilliamPursell I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help on same.

```
awk '{split($0,a,"[:-]");print a[1],a[2]+$2,a[2]+$2+1}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk -F":|-| +" '{print $1,$2+$4,$2+$4+1}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[-:\t]' -v OFS='\t' '{t=$2+$4; print $1, t, t+1}' file
chr10   100007599       100007600
chr8    100007611       100007612
chr6    100007616       100007617
chr1    100007448       100007449
```